# How to center a list of icons on en amil (email html)

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, html-email

I'd just like to put in an email a series of 4 social icons centered (horizontally) but they keep being put by gmail and yahoo on the left side!

```
    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;-webkit-font-smoothing:  antialiased;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;height: 100%;width: 100%;">
    <table style="margin: 0;padding: 0;width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #F2F2F2;">
    <tr>
        <td style="margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;display: block;max-width: 600px;clear: both; align: center; valign: top; background-color:#ffffff ;">
          <table width="100%" style="padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center">
            <tbody>
              <tr>                
                <td style="float:left;margin-left:6px;margin-right:6px;margin-top:10px; margin-bottom: 30px;">
                  <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="<%= t("social_urls.facebook_page_url") %>">
                    <img src="http://d2vsjqr9p2w23h.cloudfront.net/email-images/facebook_icon.png" alt="Facebook">
                  </a>
                </td>
                <td style="float:left;margin-left:6px;margin-right:6px;margin-top:10px;">
                  <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="#">
                    <img src="http://d2vsjqr9p2w23h.cloudfront.net/email-images/twitter_icon.png" alt="Twitter">
                  </a>
                </td>
                <td style="float:left;margin-left:6px;margin-right:6px;margin-top:10px;">
                  <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="#">
                    <img src="http://d2vsjqr9p2w23h.cloudfront.net/email-images/pinterest_icon.png" alt="Pinterest">
                  </a>
                </td>
                <td style="float:left;margin-left:6px;margin-right:6px;margin-top:10px;">
                  <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="#">
                    <img src="http://d2vsjqr9p2w23h.cloudfront.net/email-images/tumblr_icon.png" alt="Tumblr">
                  </a>
                </td>
                <td style="float:left;margin-left:6px;margin-right:6px;margin-top:10px;">
                  <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="#">
                    <img src="http://d2vsjqr9p2w23h.cloudfront.net/email-images/instagram_icon.png" alt="Instagram">
                  </a>
                </td>
              </tr>                     
            </tbody>
          </table>                      
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
  </body>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MsVwV/).

I want them not split over the whole line but quite "concentrated" as you see each icon must only have a few pixels horizontally between them (6px left, 6px right)

Comment: Try the css rule `vertical-align: middle;` on the TD or on the IMG tag

Comment: @MrYoshiji Vertical-align ? even if my problem is that they are aligned left : seems more a pb of horizontal than vertical, no ?

Comment: CSS aligning is not fully supported in email. use the html align="" or valign="" attributes instead

Comment: @John I know John. but as you see i have put align: center and valign on <td> and <table> and nothing works, it's still aligned on the lefT.

Comment: Also, float and margin are not fully supported in email.

Comment: @Mathieu Added an example to my answer

Comment: i added a jdfiddle version so you can see the problem

Comment: @Mathieu See the jsfiddle in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In email always use `align="left|center|right"` for horizontal alignment and `valign="top|middle|bottom"` for vertical. Apply this to your table cells `<td align="center">` in your case.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YUpJu/) with two methods that will work

Here is a very basic example of both align and valign:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#252525">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" height="100">
      <img style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0;" src="" width="30" height="30" alt="">
      <img style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0;" src="" width="30" height="30" alt="">
      <img style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0;" src="" width="30" height="30" alt="">
      <img style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0;" src="" width="30" height="30" alt="">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i'll try but the problem as shows the jsfiddle version is on horizontal! it's aligned left while i would like it to be centered !

Comment: Sorry, then align="center" in your case. this example works, just remove valign from the table cell if you don't want it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that should be `text-align: center` instead of just `align: center` in your main table data cell (because you're calling it as a css style parameter). Also, `vertical-align` instead of `valign`.

If that doesn't do it, try adding `text-align: center;` to the table style, then switch out the `float:left` on each `td` so they're `display: inline-block;` instead.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT---------------------------------------------------------------------------

How about this approach using only tables?

Check the [new Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaunp/MsVwV/3/)

### HTML

```
<table style="margin: 0;padding: 0;width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #F2F2F2;">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="20%" />        
        <col width="60%" /> 
        <col width="20%" />             
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center">
        <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="#">
            <img src="http://d2vsjqr9p2w23h.cloudfront.net/email-images/facebook_icon.png" alt="Facebook" />
        </a>
        <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="#">
            <img src="http://d2vsjqr9p2w23h.cloudfront.net/email-images/twitter_icon.png" alt="Twitter" />
        </a> 
        <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="#">
            <img src="http://d2vsjqr9p2w23h.cloudfront.net/email-images/pinterest_icon.png" alt="Pinterest" />
        </a>
        <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="#">
            <img src="http://d2vsjqr9p2w23h.cloudfront.net/email-images/tumblr_icon.png" alt="Tumblr" />
        </a> 
        <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="#">
            <img src="http://d2vsjqr9p2w23h.cloudfront.net/email-images/instagram_icon.png" alt="Instagram /" />
        </a>            
        </td>
        <td>
        </td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: yes on emails you can't use divs so best practice is to use old fashioned tables:(

Comment: Darn... that would have been too easy I guess.